# CSS: Weird lines when using a scale-transition

Tags: html, css, animation, dom, css-transitions

I am experiencing some weird issues with CSS scale transitions. The scaling works fine, however there are some weird lines around the scaled element, which disappear after scrolling. This happened in a Chrome browser and in Microsoft Edge. And I don't assume it has something to do with margin, padding, the z-index, colors or anything else along those lines, because it happened with and without these properties being included in the relevant CSS.

This is the relevant CSS as a quick draft:

```css
.element {
    background-color:black;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    transform:scale(1, 1, 1);
}

.element:hover {
    transform:scale(1.1, 1.1);
}
```

Here is a quick recording to demonstrate that: https://streamable.com/cyvkjm

Here is also a screenshot for those who can't see the video for some reason:
[image]

Comment: This link (https://streamable.com/cyvkjm) is not working!

Comment: That is weird. It is working fine for me. I will include a screenshot in the post for those who can't see the video. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Try opening in another browser, where you have not logged in to streamable!

Answer (score 1):

Your streamable link worked fine for me. I remember having a problem similar to that a while ago, and it was something to do with using 3d scaling
Check this out though, I'm fairly certain backface-visibility: hidden and the -webkit equivalent will fix it. As I can't reproduce this I can't be of much more help
[CSS transition on element leaving lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25799480/css-transition-on-element-leaving-lines)

Edit: after reproducing the problem we found a fix. Tested and works in Chrome/Edge/Firefox. perspective(1000px) seems to work better than perspective(0)

```
.element {
  transform: scale(1) perspective(1000px);
}
.element:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1) perspective(1000px);
}
```

Comment: Hello there! Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately, neither applying backface-visibility: hidden; to the element's CSS nor -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); or transform: translateZ(0); worked out in the end. Even a combination of all of them didn't work out in the end. Your help is very much appreciated though, thank you very much!

Comment: Make sure you used -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; if on Chrome, but anyways best of luck

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work either. Not even in combination with all the other solutions. Thank you very much for your help though! I appreciate that.

Comment: I may have found a fix for you if, just add perspective(0); onto the end of your transform.

Comment: Thank you a lot! The perspective(1000px) worked better than perspective(0), indeed. I really appreciate your help, thank you very much! The weird behaviour doesn't occur anymore.